# Creating loop with random timing and input of short phrase into Explorer window

Tags: internet-explorer, loops, random

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the script below; doesn't work.

My goal is to have my script start by finding an IE window I've already opened to a page I want to input text into. It would then activate & maximize the window, type in text in a specified location, and click the "send" button on the page. It would then wait a random amount of time and repeat the same text typing and send.

This is my first attempt at a script. What have I done wrong?

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Recommended for catching common errors. 
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Pause::Pause  
#q::ExitApp 

SetTitleMatchMode 2

IfWinExist, ahk_class IEFrame 
{
WinActivate  
WinMaximize 
}

random, sleeptime, 180000, 300000 
loop 
{ 

Click 101, 552 
Send text phrase goes here 
Click 86,638

sleep, %sleeptime% 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this script is almost completely correct.
You just need to move the lines:
`Pause::Pause`
`#q::ExitApp`
to the bottom.

Any lines above the first hotkey label, (in this case `Pause::Pause`,)
will run when the script is opened, those lines are called the auto-execute section. Any lines including and below the first hotkey label require a hotkey to be triggered in order to run them.

Thus the code from `SetTitleMatchMode 2` onwards needs to be moved up (the same as moving the `Pause` and `#q` lines down) to put it in the auto-execute section, or, a new hotkey label needs to be added above the line `SetTitleMatchMode 2` to trigger that block of code.